# What type of activity animation view is this?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, ios5

In the picture below, what type of view is used to create the 'turning on reminders' activity indicator? Is it a custom view with a label and a standard UIActivityIndicator? a built in UIKit class?

[image: activity indicator]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said, it is a custom view. Fortunately, a kind third party has created a nice open source implementation:

https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Answer (score 2):

yes it is view with a label and a standard UIActivityIndicator.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a custom view.  Something like this completely untested code would do it:

```
- (UIView *)busyOverlayViewWithText:(NSString *)text {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 120, 160, 160)];
    view.opaque = NO;
    view.clipsToBounds = YES;
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:.2];
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 8;

    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    spinner.center = CGPointMake(80, 30);
    [spinner startAnimating];
    [view addSubview:spinner];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, 160, 100)];
    label.text = text;
    label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor;
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    [view addSubview:label];

    return view;
}
```

this is using ARC. Add (auto)releases if you use manual memory management.

Comment: What you have created is just a custom view. So "You don't need a custom view" is wrong. Also I suspect memory problem in your code.

Comment: To me, "custom view" means a subclass of `UIView`.

Comment: Also, there's no memory problem in my code.  I used ARC when I didn't test it.

Comment: Custom view means something that can not be achieved by a single built-in view. It does not matter whether inheritance or object composition is used. You should have mentioned about ARC (I must agree that I'm not much familiar with this). Without ARC there are definite problems. Anyway, I have not downvoted you because of the code example (and as you have already admitted that the code is not tested).

Comment: so "You don't need a custom view" should read "you don't need a third-party UIView subclass that uses 1200 lines of code.".

Comment: Could you please point to me to the Apple documentation or the ISO standard definition of "custom view"?  Because I can't find it.

Comment: and I fixed two problems in the code. So this is now tested code.

Comment: Rob and Mathias - thanks for putting together a great example!  Your solution is definitely much simpler than the above referenced open sourced project.  With the combination of the two answers I'll definitely be able to put together something nice for the app.  Thank you guys once again! Great work... (Btw, I kinda figured you were using ARC from the beginning - it's the concept on how to construct such an object that matters really).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a single built-in class. Rather it is a composition of:

- A custom transparent view, possibly an image.
- A standard activity indicator.
- A standard label.

If you want to create something similar then you can easily put them all in a single class.

Comment: Thank you! I just wanted to check before I went ahead and tried to reinvent the wheel...